# moderncv maketitle override

Tags: titles, moderncv

I'm using `moderncv` to create my resume and I'm satisfied with the entire document aside from the title. I'm hoping to change `\makecvtitle` to create it to my liking, but there are a few things I'm not sure how to do in LaTeX.

1. I'd like a colored banner across the top of the page
2. I'd like text to go over said banner
3. I'd like to place an image over part of the banner as well
4. If possible, I'd like to use the github, email, and phone icons from moderncv

This is my desired result for the title:

[image: desired result]

How would I go about doing these things?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.  What do you have so far?  Could you provide a starting point for us?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is probably to `\usepackage{tikz}` and its `tikzpicture` environment. Remove the `\makecvtitle` macro and replace it with something like this:

```
%\makecvtitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
% the colored background - as wide as the text, one inch high
\fill[blue](0,1) rectangle ++(\textwidth,1in);

% the picture, with a 5 pt wide white margin    
\node[inner sep=5pt,fill=white] at (0.75\textwidth,1in) {\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}};

% the large white text on the colored background

% some right-aligned text below the colored bar
\node[font=\Large,text=white] at (0.25\textwidth,1.2in) {My name here};
\node[align=right] at (0.5\textwidth,0.5in) {Stuff about me\\more stuff about me};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.5in} % some vertical space before the regular text starts
```

[image]